# Insert from one table to another with more columns

Tags: mysql, insert

In order to save time on a large 5M record table with many indexes since

`Alter TableA Add Column X`

would have taken forever given the # of indexes and data I first copied it w/o data;

```
Create TableB Like TableA
```

Then I added a field using

`Alter TableB Add Column X`

Now I'm trying to copy the data over with

```
Insert TableB Select * from TableA
```

Except I'm getting

```
> 1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

The table I'm inserting into has more columns so unsure how it is an issue. Is there some command I need to add or do I need to specify all the columns in the Insert and Select?

Answer (score 0):

Best practice in this case *would* in fact be to explicitly list out all columns in your insert statement.  This is true even if the number of columns were the same.

However, if the order and types of the columns in table A match the columns in table B, minus column X, which was added at the end, then you could use the following:

```
INSERT INTO TableB
SELECT *, NULL         -- NULL will be inserted into column X
FROM TableA;
```

Again, the above will only work with the given caveats.  If at all possible, you should list out the columns.

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good idea to avoid implicit lists of columns. Instead, list the columns explicitly. That way if the tables ever change, your query will still have a chance of working.

Listing columns explicitly, you would write your query this way:

```
Insert TableB (col1, col2, col3)
Select colA, colB, colC from TableA
```

If TableB has additional columns, just don't list them in the column list in the first line. The value on rows inserted using this statement will either be NULL, or else use the DEFAULT defined for the column if one is defined.